# Eliminar index.php de la URL en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter

Saludos desarrolladores.

he subido mi proyecto de codeigniter a un host. todo funciona bien menos el archivo .htaccess que no elimina el index.php de la url's.

el host esta asi srv/www/msn/proyecto
dentro de "/msn/ esta el proyecto de codeIgniter y dentro de el esta el archivo .htaccess...

ejemplo srv/www/msn/proyecto/.htaccess

dentro del archivo .htaccess tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php?/*(.*) / [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

ademas tengo el archivo config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.myhost.com/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

cuando estoy en la pagina principal https://www.myhost.com/ hago clic en un boton que me lleva a la vista "team" la url se cambia a esta https://www.myhost.com/index.php/primary/team

el mod_rewrite esta habilitado

estoy haciendo algo mal?

que puede estar pasando?

por favor agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu proyecto codeigniter esta un subdirectorio y el index del proyecto esta en ese mismo lugar debes agregar en `RewriteBase` el nombre de tu subdirectorio por que lo estabas redirigiendo a tu carpeta raíz `/`:

Aqui un ejemplo de un `.htaccess` de codeigniter para un subdirectorio:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /tusubdirectorio
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: agregue el subdirectorio el RewriteBase /msn y no ha funcionado